# Cycle through different images on hover

Tags: javascript, css, image, hover

I have some cards I've designed through bootstrap, upon hovering, an image covers the card.  I want to be able to cycle through 3 different images every time you re-hover.
I've made it this far, where upon hovering an image will show up, however its not cycling through because it is pulling all images at once and only 'portrait_02.jpg" is showing due to its positioning, I'm unsure where to go next.  Help would be appreciated.

HTML + JS

```js
                        var containerOne = document.getElementById("myImage");
                        var urls = [ 'portrait_01.jpg',
                                     'portrait_02.jpg',
                                     'portrait_03.jpg'];

                        for(i=0; i < urls.length; i++){
                          containerOne.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<img class="oImageSize" src="../images/cards/' + urls[i] + '">');
                        }
```

```css
    .overlayContainer {
     position: relative;
     width: 50%;
    }

    .overlay {
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     width: 100%;
     height: 0;
     transition: .5s ease;
    }

    .overlayContainer:hover .overlay {
     height: 100%;
     opacity: 1;
    }


    .oImageSize {
     display: block;
     width: 320px;
     height: 320px;
    }

    .oImage {
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
                      <div class="card overlayContainer" style="width: 20rem;">

                        <div class="overlay">
                          <div id="myImage" class="oImage">
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-header"> <h2> Portraits </h2>
                        <h5 class="card-title"> $80-45mins-20prints</h5>
                      </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                          <p class="card-text">
                            <ul>
                              <li> Lipsum </li>
                              <li> Lipsum </li>
                              <li> Lipsum </li>
                              <li> Lipsum </li>
                              <li> Lipsum </li>
                            </ul>
                          </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
```

Comment: I would think you would need the onmouseover event and increment a counter.

Comment: I've been trying this for a while now, and it works however i think i've got my counter in the wrong space as it keeps displaying the same image.  
Sorry and thank you, i'm newish to JS.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop blasts thru and inserts one image after another. You'll want to replace images with a pause inbetween. Something like this. Untested.

```
int counter=1;
while(true){
     containerOne.html('<img class="oImageSize" src="../images/cards/' + urls[counter] + '">');
sleep(1000);
    counter++;
    counter=counter%3;
}

//https://www.phpied.com/sleep-in-javascript/
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't quite understand how to get this to work.  I did try it and fiddle around with it but still no luck.  I'm newish to JS and could just be my lack of skills.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  I don't know if you can adapt this or not.  It does cycle.  It was educational for me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#img1 { display:none; position:fixed; left:100px; top:10px; }
#img2 { display:none; position:fixed; left:100px; top:10px; }
#img3 { display:none; position:fixed; left:100px; top:10px; }
</style>
<script>
  "use strict";
  var nimg = 1;
function show() {
  var imgx = "img" + nimg;
  var elt = document.getElementById(imgx);
  elt.style = "display:block;";
}
function hide() {
  var imgx = "img" + nimg;
  var elt = document.getElementById(imgx);
  elt.style = "display:none;";
  nimg = 1 + nimg % 3;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div onmouseover="show();" onmouseout="hide();" >
  MouseOverMe
</div>
<div id="img1"><img src="img1.jpg"/></div>
<div id="img2"><img src="img2.jpg"/></div>
<div id="img3"><img src="img3.jpg"/></div>
</body>
</html>
```